# Complex Alignment of Divs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive

Here a situation comes, where Two divs are bound to design from Database.

I am trying to align two `div`s as follows:
[image: Desired HTML]

Is it possible using bootstrap's CSS class `col-`?
In responsive mode, it should look in **Tablet mode** as follows:
[image: HTML in Tablet mode]

Note: 1. trying to accomplish mostly using CSS only.
2. *Div 1* & *Div 2* is under single Div

Comment: use raw class container  for each div <div class=row"> Div 1 </div> and on

Comment: @HeadInCloud U mean, to use 3 separate containers?

Comment: yes three different container

Comment: trying on 3 `<div class="row">`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to re answer this for you.

Flexbox is a great way to utilise and position things here is basically exactly what you're looking for made with flexbox. Widths etc may need a tinker to perfect it but this would be the overall finish:

```css
aside {
  background: yellow;
}

main {
  background: blue;
}

footer {
  background: pink;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

footer {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

aside {
  flex-basis: 300px;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside>
    some text here
  </aside>
  
  <main>
    more text here
  </main>
  
  <footer>
    footer text
  </footer>
</div>
```

Flexbox is pretty much supported on all browsers now so you'd have no issue in using it on your works, I use it a lot of the time. Here's a reference of things you can do with Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

UPDATED: You can refer to what works on what browser by visiting: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

I update the answer with new class and css

**css**

```
@media (max-width: 1027px) {
 .div1 {
    margin-right: 2px;
  }

}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 div1" style="background-color:lavender;">div 1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 div3" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">div 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 div2" style="background-color:lavender;">div 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you wanted to do like second image on responsive?

Comment: @Vikrant Check now i have updated the css for responsive device width

Comment: please work your code on fiddle and place it to help your code to update

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to use CSS flexbox because you are able to easily manipulate the order/layout when displaying elements.

```
.container-div {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.item-div-1 {
order: 1;
...
}

.item-div-2 {
order: 3;
...
}

.item-div-3 {
order: 2;
...
}
```

You can find more information about specific flex-box properties at [CSS-Tricks: A guide to flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).
Only thing to remember is make sure you check browser compatibility. I believe there's no support in I.E.-8 and below.

Comment: can you place Link of **CSS-Tricks: A guide to flexbox** in your answer?